# How to compile PushNotifications code for ios only not for android in Titanium

Tags: titanium-mobile

I am using Push-notifications code its working fine for ios but because of that not running in Android is there any way so that I can put any condition so that that particular code compile/run for ios and for android skip that particular code?

Comment: Done Successfully..follow my communication with Robert on below url..

http://developer.appcelerator.com/question/131680/sdk-181-android-modules-problem

Answer (score 0):

try `Titanium.Platform.osname != "android"`
or `Titanium.Platform.osname == "iphone"`

you can find more options [here](http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/2.0/#!/api/Titanium.Platform)